# Batman Arkham City crashes when interrogating riddler informants

Tags: technical-issues, batman-arkham-city

Every time I want to interrogate a Riddler informant, the game crashes with some fatal error.

I interrogated 3 or 4 Riddler informants at the very beginning of the game. But then, I tried interrogating another one and the game crashed for the first time. After this "first crash" I can't interrogate anyone without getting a crash.

Did I do something wrong? it's a bug that I'm not aware of? Anybody knows how I can fix this?

***PS: That is, by the way, the only situation in which the game crashes.***

Cheers

### Some system info

- Laptop ASUS K52JE.
- Windows 7 64bit SP1.
- 2GB Ram p6100 2GHz.
- ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470.
- DirectX 11 newest version.

Comment: What are your system configurations ?

Comment: good point... edited and added some info

Comment: Small changes to better "layout" hope you like it =)

Comment: try reinstalling (or verify the integrity of your game cache if you are on steam)

Comment: Is this a licensed/registered copy of Arkham City?

Comment: Just a note, I'm playing with worse specs than that, and have never had an issue, all the way to 100% completion.

Comment: I finally had some time to check this out. A reinstall fixed the problem and I can now interrogate them just fine.
Thanks for the help.